# How to identify what application is using this port (lsof / fuser not helping)?

Tags: linux, http

How do I find what process/application is running an http server on a machine? All the Usual tools (netstat, lsof, fuser, ss aren't helping in this instance)

```
vinayb@carbon ~ $ sudo fuser 80/tcp
vinayb@carbon ~ $ sudo ss -pt state listening 'sport = :80'
Recv-Q    Send-Q       Local Address:Port       Peer Address:Port    Process    
vinayb@carbon ~ $ curl http://localhost:80
404 page not found
vinayb@carbon ~ $ curl -vv http://localhost:80
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.73.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Date: Sat, 27 Feb 2021 12:45:05 GMT
< Content-Length: 19
<
```

Answer (score 0):

Using netstat usually helps in this case, ie. `netstat -tupan`.

Best executed as root, that will give you a nice list, such as:

```
tom:~/ $ sudo netstat -tupan
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1450/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1764/smbd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1764/smbd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1106/sshd
...
```

Comment: Try ss -lnp | grep 80